# Raise event in C++ win32 and catch in C#

Tags: c#, c++, events

I have an application in C++ which handles 4 devices in 4 threads synchronously. My company wants a GUI for that. I wanted to know, is it possible, to raise events in unmanaged C++ and catch them in C#? (I'd prefer GUI in .net, because of simplicity of my GUI needs).
I mean, for example, when

`SetEvent(something_changed_event_InCPP);`

in C# This satisfies:

`CPPEvent.WaitOne();`

Please note, I need and prefer to use events, no network, no shared memory, no etc.
A sample is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarity: you want an unmanaged C++ main program to raise an event for a C# dll which is linked to the unmanaged code.

Comment: @cup No. My .net GUI is an executable file, and totally independent from C++ program. when GUI runs, It will receive events from C++ program and should send back events. no dll import is done, noting is linked. I want this, because my C++ application, runs independent of users, as PC powers on. but GUI is a user thing and operator runs it when he logged on.